# Why is nock matching request when body, time and timeout should not match?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nock

I have a service request nocked, I expect a nock error (nock: No match for request POST) in this case but getting a successful response. wondering why!

```
nock(`http://localhost`, {
                reqheaders: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .post('/')
            .reply(201, function () {
                return fs.readFileSync(`./data/mock-response.json`, 'utf8');
            });
```

and the actual service call is

```
    request(
    url: 'http://localhost/',
    time:true,
    timeout: 5000,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Content-Type: 'application/json
    },
    body: {
        test:'test'}
```

)

Am not matching on the following parameters with nock
body,time,timeout
still nocks returns me the right son

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `body` in your `nock` object otherwise nock will just intercept it based on the URL and verb.

As per the [official nock documentation](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#specifying-request-body), a body must be specified in order to be matched.

Your nock object would look something like this:

```
nock(`http://localhost`, {
  reqheaders: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.post('/', {
  test: 'test'
})
.reply(201, function () {
  return fs.readFileSync(`./data/mock-response.json`, 'utf8');
});
```

Comment: thats my understanding too, but whatever I have above without the body is returning me a response, thats what is confusing me. why is my example not throwing NOCK no match found error

Answer (score 0):

According to doc: You **can** specify the request body to be matched as the second argument to the get, post, put or delete specifications.

It does not say **must**. All posts will match if no body is specified.